# Version control system that preserves file properties

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Is there any version control system that could preserve file properties like permissions, owner, time stamp etc ?

I need such a system in order to keep track of the content of a virtual machine root filesystem.

UPDATE:
After reading the code of etckeeper, I ended up implementing my own keeper in Python https://github.com/torshie/anykeeper . Mainly because etckeeper doesn't keep track of device files and pipes, and also has performance problems when keeping a large directory.

Comment: Why not just use the VM snapshot capabilities that are (probably) built into your virtualization system?

Comment: You might look at [etckeeper](https://github.com/joeyh/etckeeper)

Comment: @Chris, snapshot doesn't support branch/merge/diff and many others. I need to change the content frequently like editing source code, and also keep track of all the changes.

Comment: @o11c etckeeper seems to be close to what I want, not sure whether it could take care of an arbitrary directory.

Comment: @user416983 I know it can because I patched the config file to work with gentoo-prefix.

Comment: After reading the code of etckeeper, I ended up implementing my own keeper in Python https://github.com/torshie/anykeeper . Mainly because etckeeper doesn't keep track of device files and pipes, and also has performance problems when keeping a large directory.